# How can one pass the Scala version string to a code generator for SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

When using code generators with SBT, one uses constructs like

```
def genFile(out: File): Seq[File] = {
  val file = new File(out, "generated.scala")
  // Add stuff to file
  Seq(file)
}

(sourceGenerators in Compile) <+= (sourceManaged in Compile) map (genFile _)
```

If your generator needs the Scala version string, how do you pass it in?  Using `scalaVersion.value` in `genFile` results in an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the good old way. I'm sure there is a newer approach where you define `genFile` as a custom task and that would enable `scalaVersion.value`.

```
// build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

def genFile(out: File, v: String): Seq[File] = {
  out.mkdirs()
  val f = out / "generated.scala"
  val w = new java.io.FileOutputStream(f)
  w.write(s"""package object foo {
             |  val scalaVersion = "$v"
             |}
             |""".stripMargin.getBytes("UTF-8"))
  w.close()
  Seq(f)
}

(sourceGenerators in Compile) <+=
  (sourceManaged in Compile, scalaVersion in Compile) map genFile
```

---

```
$ sbt console
...
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_65).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> foo.scalaVersion
res0: String = 2.11.2
```

Comment: *sigh*...thank you.  Foolish question, as I tried this exact thing and didn't realize that the problem wasn't actually passing in the version, but that I put it in the wrong place in the list of arguments to `<+=` (I already had five in the real use case).  I haven't the foggiest idea how I was supposed to know where it should go.  (For reference: _third_ was cool.  _sixth_ was not.)

Comment: (Actually, it was `map` that was unhappy, not `<+=`.)